# Angular 2's Animation Builder easing function

Tags: javascript, css-animations, angular

The documentation is unclear about this one - is there a way to change the easing function (e.g., ease-in, ease-out) when using angular2 AnimationBuilder?

I tried to set the animation-timing-function in the from/to styles but without luck.

Comment: I haven't found a direct way (using AnimationBuilder itself), but you can add `transition-timing-function:xxxxx` in your element and it will use that one.

Comment: @EricMartinez, Thanks it worked - although I hoped for a less hackish solution :)

Comment: You can use `host` as well like `host : {'[style.transition-timing-function]' : "'linear'"}` in your component/directive class. It would basically the same. We just have to wait until the new API arrives.